# How to handle namespace API versioning with DRF-YASG

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

In my project we want to have multiple versions of same api so as to support backward compatibility.
Right now we are using drf-yasg's swagger url at
/api/doc/
While our apis are
/api/vehicle/$
/api/warehouse/

And then each of the app vehicle and ware house have their own endpoints..

Now we want to do versioning as
/api/v1/doc
/api/v2/doc
/api/v1/vehicle
/api/v2/vehicle
/api/v1/warehouse

Goal is that /v1/doc should show v1 of both vehicle and ware house while/v2/doc should show only v2 of vehicle since only vehicle app has some apis with v2....
How to achieve this

I tried adding default version v1 initially in drf settings. But that resulted in no listing being shown in swagger view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into this same issue recently and was able to resolve it like so,

in my root app urls

```
# myapp/urls.py

...
path('api/v1/', include('api.v1.urls'),
                   name='v1'),
path('api/v2/', include('api.v2.urls'),
                   name='v2'),
...
```

then I created an app specifically to handle all api routes with different versions, inside this app i have a module for each of the versions I have as well as the urls for swagger/redoc like that

```
api/
    __init__.py
   |
   v1/
     |
      __init__.py
      urls.py
   v2/
     |
      __init__.py
      urls.py
```

In each of the version urls, I added the urls for the specific app apis and the urls for docs like so

```
# app/v1/urls.py

from django.urls import path, include
from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('app1/', include('app1.api.v1.urls'), name='app1-api-v1'),
    path('app2/', include('app2.api.v1.urls'), name='app2-api-v1'),
    path('app3/', include('app3.api.v1.urls'), name='app3-api-v1'),
]

schema_view = get_schema_view(openapi.Info(
    title="My API",
    default_version='v1',
    description="My REST API documentation",
    contact=openapi.Contact(email="dev@myapp.com"),
),
    public=True, patterns=urlpatterns)

urlpatterns += [
    path('swagger/',
     schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0),
     name='schema-swagger-ui-v1'),
    path('redoc/',
     schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0),
     name='schema-redoc-v1'),
]
```

Did the same for api/v2/urls.py with the corresponding changes to the urls and naming. This way I had 2 separate urls for each of version of the api docs.

Hope this helps!